# Java RegEx replaceAll throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, regex

I am trying in Java to surround a word in HTML with some markup. This code throws a **ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException** when the **replaceAll** is called.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(wordToHighlight + "\\w{0,5}");
String replacement = "<span class='highlight'>$1</span>";
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(html);

if (matcher != null)
    if (matcher.find())
        retVal = matcher.replaceAll(replacement);
```

Comment: What does `html` contain at that point?

Comment: Who cares? This is a simplistic attempt to highlight search text in an arbitrary HTML string. There are countless ways this can go wrong, but it will work in most cases. Users can have fun with interesting effects if they include angle brackets in their search expressions.

Comment: FYI, neither `if (matcher != null)` nor `if (matcher.find())` in your code is doing anything useful.  If the code reaches that point `matcher` *can't* be `null` (it would have thrown an exception), and the first thing `replaceAll()` does is call `find()`.  If that returns `false` it just returns the original string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try putting a capturing group on your search expression. i.e. wrap your string in parentheses.

i.e.

```
"(" + wordToHighlight + "\\w{0,5})"
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm not familiar with Regex in Java so I'll just go ahead and make a guess, excuse me if I'm way off base. In PCRE (PHP) $1 would refer to the first capture group, since you don't have a capture group that could throw an error. Try using $0.

Answer (score 0):

Try four backslashes:

Pattern.compile(wordToHighlight + "\\w{0,5}");

Somehow the escaping takes place twice. That means:

1.) \\ turns into \

2.) then \ turns into \

Comment: Now the damn editor escaped my answer.

Comment: Second try: 1.) \\\\\\\\ turns into \\\\ then 2.) \\\\ turns into \\

Comment: Now the editor did not escape my answer.

Comment: Third try: 1.) \\\\ turns into \\ then 2.) \\ turns into \

Comment: YES !!!! Now it's okay !!!!

Comment: Pattern.compile(wordToHighlight + "\\\\w{0,5}");

Comment: Please update your answer via the edit button and remove the comments.

Comment: The [markdown help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) shows how to make the code appear as you typed it by using backticks or indenting.  But this is not the solution the OP was looking for.  The Java string literal `"\\\\w"` would become the literal string `\\w`, which is the regex for a backslash followed by a 'w'.